I try to create a job using job definition in AWS batch but i am getting runnable status every time
enter image description here
Steps I follow to create job:

First create a compute environment and choose Provisioning model as EC2 and Instance type vt1.3xlarge and get status valid.
Create Queue.
Create Job definition in which Orchestration type I choose Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2).
a. In command I put following code:added screenshot
After creting I try to create job getting runnable status everytime.


if your AWS Batch job remains stuck in the RUNNABLE status, it typically indicates that the job is waiting for a compute resource to become available or there is a configuration issue preventing the job from running. without the full Batch - job definition, and policies configuration we cannot help much to know the core issue.

please replace the image by a code block containing the actual text you want to share.
